# How to debug Remote Application running on tomcat server from intellJ Idea

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, jvm, remote-debugging

Hi I have been trying to setup remote debugging of my application that is running on the internet(server) with tomcat 7.0.50. And I have developed it using IntelliJ Idea 13.0.1.

I have gone through many tutorials for setting up my application on remote tomcat to debug from my local intelliJ idea. but i could not find any thing helpful or working.

Is there some one who has set up remote debugging for his/her self?

Please can any one share the step by step instruction tutorial to set up remote debugging from intelliJ Idea to Tomcat Server.

BEST Regards.

Comment: It doesn't help you when you don't share what you have tried that 'did not work'. I can't believe that you try different resources and they ALL provide wrong information, there is something that you are missing yourself here. Are you even sure that your remote server allows connections to be made on the port you are setting up?

Comment: On server, my app listens to port 5005 for debug, I set up a remote debugging configuration in intelliJ idea and using IP of server as host. It does not get connected. I get request time out error.

Comment: This and similar like this did not worked for me http://www.srivatsakatta.com/2009/04/remote-debugging-using-intellij.html

Comment: Perhaps you have some sort of firewall or port blocker between you and that machine. Check with your ops guys.